# Input loop becomes de-synchronized

Tags: loops, synchronization, autohotkey

So I have tried making an autohotkey input script to automate a really tedious amount of data entry at work. Basically, I have it set up so that it pulls data from an Excel spreadsheet into our database program, via copy and paste, and some manual entry for things that remain constant.

It asks a user for the number of parts to enter and then loops that many times.

My issue is that inevitably, after a few loops through the process, it becomes desynced, and then can't continue properly and it has to start over.

I've tried a few different things, including setting the key delay higher and adding various "Sleep, xxx" lines throughout, but the problem persisted.

```
 setKeyDelay, 60,60

F1::

Gui, Add, Picture, , I:\TPM MAINTENANCE\Robb's BoM Input Macro\BB.PNG

Gui, Add, text, , Enter # of Parts:

Gui, Add, Edit, vNum

Gui, Add, Button, default, OK

Gui, Show

Return


ButtonOK:

Gui, Submit 

/*Loop Variables

Counter := 1

Percentage := 100 / Num

Start := 0

Progress, w500,, Adding Parts..., BoM Macro

Loop, %Num%

{


/* Item Category and Unit of Measurement

    Send N{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}EA{ENTER}

/* Grabs Quantity from Excel

    Winactivate, Microsoft Excel
    winwaitactive, Microsoft Excel, , 10
    Send ^c
    WinActivate, Create material BOM
    WinWaitActive, Create material BOM, , 10
    Send ^v
    Send {ENTER}

/*Grabs Description from Excel

    Winactivate, Microsoft Excel
    winwaitactive, Microsoft Excel, , 10
    Send {RIGHT}
    Send ^c
    Winactivate, Create material BOM
    winwaitactive, Create material BOM, , 10
    Send ^v

/*Grabs Manufacturer Part Number from Excel

    Winactivate, Microsoft Excel
    winwaitactive, Microsoft Excel, , 10
    Send {RIGHT}
    Send ^c
    Winactivate Create material BOM
    winwaitactive, Create material BOM, , 10
    Send {TAB}{TAB}
    Send ^v
    Send {ENTER}

/*Entering Purchasing Data

    Send .0
    Send {TAB}{TAB}
    Send G04
    Send {TAB}{TAB}

    Winactivate, Microsoft Excel
    winwaitactive, Microsoft Excel, , 10
    Send {RIGHT}
    Send ^c
    Winactivate, Create material BOM
    winwaitactive, Create material BOM, , 10
    Send ^v

    Send {TAB}{TAB}{TAB}
    Send PM002
    Send {ENTER}

/*Pointing Excel at the next item

    Winactivate, Microsoft Excel
    winwaitactive, Microsoft Excel, , 10
    Send {LEFT}{LEFT}{LEFT}{DOWN}
    Winactivate, Create material BOM
    winwaitactive, Create material BOM, , 10

/*Loop to correctly position SAP pointer


    Loop, %Counter%
    {
    Send {DOWN} 
    }   

    Send {TAB}
    Counter++
    Increment := ++start
    Result := Percentage * Increment

    Progress, %Result%

}

Progress, 100
Sleep, 800
Progress, off
GuiClose:
Gui, Destroy
```

Comment: 1.) instead of switching between the windows after each copy, you could also work with the contents of the `clipboard` variable. This will probably minimize the chance for the script to mess up. I would have loved to show an example, but the stupid comment section won't let me do that.
2.) instead of `Counter`, you could also access the built-in variable `A_Index` for loops
3.) what exactly "becomes desynced"? Where? I assume you know roughly, for it seems your program notices this by itself (?)

Comment: 1.) I did not know about the clipboard commands--I will have to look into that. Thank you.

2.) Good idea

3.) Honestly, this is the weird part. I've had it desync as early as 2 or 3 loops, and as late as 13...I'm hoping a combination of clipboard variables and perhaps some well-timed Sleep commands could get it to chill out.

Comment: There are much easier and more reliable ways to manipulate Excel sheets. I think the best option is to use [VBA within Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb149067(v=office.12).aspx). The second option would be using the respective COM object [Excel.Application](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/56987-com-object-reference-autohotkey-v11/page-4#entry381256) in AHK.

Comment: I would be curious not about the amount of loop completions before your script falls out of sync, but moreso at which point the script breaks in the loop, and if that is consistent, regardless of the number of loops it takes to break at that point.